# Not able to store data in original riak bucket

Tags: riak, nosql

I have installed riak 2.0.1 on my machine. I am trying to store an object with a key in riak bucket. But I am stuck in a weird problem.

My actual bucket name is "**abc-client**".

When I try to save data in this bucket, I am getting below error on console:

```
[error] ! step error
[error]   RiakRetryFailedException: com.basho.riak.client.http.response.RiakResponseRuntimeException: <html><head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head><body><h1>Internal Server Error</h1>The server encountered an error while processing this request:<br><pre>{error,
[error]     {error,badarg,
[error]         [{erlang,iolist_to_binary,
[error]              [{hook_crashed,{riak_search_kv_hook,precommit,error,badarg}}],
[error]              []},
[error]          {wrq,append_to_response_body,2,[{file,"src/wrq.erl"},{line,215}]},
[error]          {riak_kv_wm_object,handle_common_error,3,
[error]              [{file,"src/riak_kv_wm_object.erl"},{line,1144}]},
[error]          {webmachine_resource,resource_call,3,
[error]              [{file,"src/webmachine_resource.erl"},{line,186}]},
[error]          {webmachine_resource,do,3,
[error]              [{file,"src/webmachine_resource.erl"},{line,142}]},
[error]          {webmachine_decision_core,resource_call,1,
[error]              [{file,"src/webmachine_decision_core.erl"},{line,48}]},
[error]          {webmachine_decision_core,accept_helper,1,
[error]              [{file,"src/webmachine_decision_core.erl"},{line,612}]},
[error]          {webmachine_decision_core,decision,1,
[error]              [{file,"src/webmachine_decision_core.erl"},{line,580}]}]}}</pre><P><HR><ADDRESS>mochiweb+webmachine web server</ADDRESS></body></html> (DefaultRetrier.java:81)
[error] com.basho.riak.client.cap.DefaultRetrier.attempt(DefaultRetrier.java:79)
[error] com.basho.riak.client.cap.DefaultRetrier.attempt(DefaultRetrier.java:81)
[error] com.basho.riak.client.cap.DefaultRetrier.attempt(DefaultRetrier.java:81)
[error] com.basho.riak.client.cap.DefaultRetrier.attempt(DefaultRetrier.java:81)
[error] com.basho.riak.client.cap.DefaultRetrier.attempt(DefaultRetrier.java:53)
[error] com.basho.riak.client.operations.StoreObject.execute(StoreObject.java:148)
```

But When I change bucket name from "**abc-client**" to "**abc-client1**", I am able to store data successfully.

Here is some part of source code

```
val bucketName = "abc-client" client.createBucket(bucketName).execute()
val abc = new ABC(id, "abc")
val bucket = client.fetchBucket(bucketName).execute() 
bucket.store(abc).execute()
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This log bit

```
[error]     {error,badarg,
[error]         [{erlang,iolist_to_binary,
[error]              [{hook_crashed,{riak_search_kv_hook,precommit,error,badarg}}],
```

is indicating that there is a precommit hook defined in the properties for `abc-client`, and that executing the defined function with the object you tried to store throws a badarg error.

Simple fix - remove the precommit hook.

More involved fix - Post the source of the function, and we'll take a look.

Comment: That might be the reason. Because I also tried to uninstall and install riak multiple times. Could you please let me know how to remove precommit hook. I have added source code above. Please check.